# Can I create a wsdl from a c# WCF service the same as I used to do with c# web service?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I have to write a web service and I want to use WCF. The developer im working with wants me to provide a wsdl. What im wondering is will I be able to use the WCF service we have in place and use a credential header like I used to with web services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

You need to add a mex endpoint (meta data exchange) and allow http get for metadata exchange.

All of these are on by default.

You just browse your service and click on the wsdl link.